# Symbol not found during build

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am now building my app and getting this error. It can't find NavUtils.
I tried adding this inside my dependencies section implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:30' but still same issue. Can anyone tell where's the issue??

```html
error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
                             ^
  symbol:   class NavUtils
  location: package android.support.v4.app
```

build.gradle file

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.prabhu.womensafetyapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 30
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:30'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
}
```

build.gradle app

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-beta06'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing support libraries and androidx libraries.

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
//implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:30'
```

The dependency `com.android.support:support-v4:30` doesn't exist.

The class `android.support.v4.app.NavUtils` is replaced by **`androidx.core.app.NavUtils`**. Change your import statements.